# ChartJS y Labels on max value

Tags: chart.js

I'm new with ChartJS v4.4.0
I would like to highlight the max value on the y axis

[image: Example of a chartJS graph]

In this example, I want the "19" value on the y axis to be in red and bold.

How can I do this ?

Thanks
JeLeB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of customizing the specific point element is similar to [@LeeLenalee's answer on Is it possible to change pointStyle for elements of a ChartJS bubble chart per dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731420/8017690).

You need to override [`options.elements.point`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#point-configuration) for the `backgroundColor` and `radius` values.

1. Get the maximum value from the datasets.

```js
let maxValue = [...dataset1, ...dataset2].sort((a, b) => b - a)[0];
```

2. Define the implementation that when the value of the point element is the `maxValue`, overwrite its value. Otherwise, use the default value.

```js
options: {
  elements: {
    point: {
      backgroundColor: (ctx) =>
        ctx.raw == maxValue
              ? 'red'
              : Chart.defaults.elements.point.backgroundColor,
      radius: (ctx) =>
        ctx.raw == maxValue ? 5 : Chart.defaults.elements.point.radius,
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

---

**Updated**

Misunderstood your question, you are looking to set the tick label in the y-axis with red color and bold but not styling the point element with the highest value.

You should overwrite the value of `scales.y.ticks.color` and `scales.y.ticks.font.weight`.

```js
scales: {
  y: {
    max: maxValue,
    ticks: {
      color: (ctx) =>
        ctx.tick.value == maxValue ? 'red' : Chart.defaults.color,
      font: {
        weight: (ctx) =>
          ctx?.tick?.value == maxValue ? 'bold' : 'normal',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-aymwhk?file=index.html)